# Van der Waerden Number Proof

Tags: inequality, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

[image: Problem]

Hi, my professor posted exactly one slide about Van der Waerden numbers and I simply don't have enough information to solve this. I tried looking online for help but none of the lower bounds seem to even closely resemble this one. Seeing as the professor gave us nothing to work with I assume we have to find some expression, e, and prove that 2^(k/2) >= e and then prove that W(k) >= e, but again, I am totally out of my element here. Could anyone please help me with this?

Edit: It's for two colours. So W(k, 2).

Comment: You might want to include the definition of $W(k)$. I'm guessing that you're just using 2 colors?

Comment: I guess so? My prof used one slide and is the only one who has ever represented it as W(k) instead of W(k, r) so I guess it's 2 colours by default?

Comment: Try using a random coloring.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color the interval $\{1,\ldots , N \} =[N]$ randomly uniformly in two colors. There are not more than $\binom{N}{2} < N^2/2$ arithmetic progressions of length $k$ in this interval. To see this, note that we can uniquely fix a $k$-AP by specifying its first two elements for instance. The probability that such a progression is monochromatic is $2 \cdot 2^{-k} = 2^{-k+1}$, as either all of the elements have color 1, or they all have color 2. So we expect less than $ N^2 2^{-k}$ monochromatic $k$-APs. If $N < 2^{k/2}$, then
$$ N^2 2^{-k}<1. $$
So if $N<2^{k/2}$, we expect less than $1$ monochromatic $k$-APs. If every coloring of $[N]$ produces a monochromatic $k$-AP, then the expected value would be at least $1$. Therefore, there is a coloring of $[N]$ with no monochromatic $k$-AP.

Comment: This is very involved. It makes sense but I just don't think I'm at the point in my course where we had the tools to solve it this way, seeing as we never even went over using probability for this problem. Thanks for your help, the more I read it the more I understand the solution. You used contradiction in the second half there.

Comment: Indeed I used contradiction. The proof I gave is usually the standard one given for this problem. I am not aware of a simpler proof. It is a (IMO) really nice example of the first moment method (first moment = expectation), which is very powerful and very beautiful, and so well worth some detailed study :)

Comment: I'll definitely be sure to look into it, even if it's not explained later in my course. Thanks again.